# in_app_purchase works differently between Test Flight and Production

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

We're using the flutter.dev in_app_purchase library.  We noticed that if there is no network (wifi and cellular are turned off) it seems to block/hang on iOS.  On Android it doesn't care.

It happens on our first call to the library, which is to check if in app purchases are available.

Any suggestions on working with in_app_purchase and handling of networking?  Why the different behavior between iOS and Android in this regard.

Comment: We've addressed the network connection. However, we now notice a new problem.  Our App Store version doesn't work. But the version in TestFlight does! Has anyone had a similar experience?

Comment: To me, _inAppPurchase.isAvailable seems to block.  We are using it just as the example shows, with an await.  Why would _inAppPurchase block on iOS when in a production environment but not in TestFlight?